# Scaffold Status Bar Blocking Button Touch

Tags: flutter, user-interface, touch, statusbar, scaffold

Although I am in **full screen mode** where **status bar is hidden** but still my **menu button** on top right corner is not receiving touch. You can see in picture where I have selected the top bar which is receiving the touch.

[image]

Half of my menu button is receiving touch and half is not.

I have Also taken picture of **Flutter Inspector** in **Widget Select Mode**

[image]

I am also adding my custom button code. Just for reference:

```
class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RoundIconButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.onPressed,
    @required this.icon,
    this.fillColor = Colors.transparent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Icon icon;
  final Function onPressed;
  final Color fillColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: icon,
      onPressed: onPressed,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      fillColor: fillColor,
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 50.0, width: 50.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap your scaffold body with safeArea widget

Comment: wrapping scaffold body with safeArea would move my widgets down as well. I don't want that.

Comment: @NoorAliButt Did you find any solution for this? I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your Scaffold with SafeArea like,

[image]

without SafeArea layout looks like:

[image]

with SafeArea layout looks like:

[image]

Comment: You can clearly see that I have a full screen app. I can not use Safe Area period

Answer (score 0):

use
Scaffold in body in child SafeArea and **SafeArea** inside insert all page
safearea has notch and bottom bar avoid

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ...........
    ...........
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and "solved" it by adding a SafeArea; this made it possible to interact with all the widgets on my screen, but the root problem was that I had a Scaffold within a Scaffold and this was causing the invisible pointer absorbing space.